# Why does Spark standalone show incorrect "Memory in use" total with dockerized worker

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Spark v3.1.2 and the standalone cluster manager but the total "Memory in use" reported in the UI is incorrect. It is reporting "1024.0 MiB Total" even though the single worker has been limited to 768MiB. Is this a bug when workers are running inside a container (docker or ECS)?

[Screenshot of master UI showing memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6RRy.png)

Setup:

- docker-compose.yml file
- 1 x master service (container)
- 1 x worker service (container)
- worker memory constrained to 768MiB and 1 CPU

Relevant section in docker-compose.yml to limit the worker container memory:

```
        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 2
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpus: "1.0"
                    memory: 768M
```

Verification docker limited the memory using "docker container inspect":

```
"Memory": 805306368
```

I've tried spinning up another worker and the UI reports a total of 2GiB in memory as it thinks each worker has 1024Mib, verified in the log:

```
INFO Master: Registering worker 172.22.0.4:7078 with 1 cores, 1024.0 MiB RAM
```

I've also tried this in ECS and observed similar behaviour.

I've also tried allocating > 1GiB to the worker in docker e.g. 5GiB and the master keeps reporting 1GiB lower? When the worker has been allocated 5GiB, the master registers the worker as having 4GiB:

`Registering worker 172.22.0.3:7078 with 1 cores, 4.0 GiB RAM`

Is this a problem with the Spark standalone cluster manager or the Spark Java worker code not able to determine the correct memory when running within a container?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of Spark UI where exactly you are seeing "memory in use"?

Comment: @VindhyaG I've added a screenshot.  It's the master UI on port 8080